# Calculating production based on growing population

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find a solution to a programing problem, but the basis is Math.
imagine a game where population grows continuously using a predetermined growth rate.

Population in time t, denoted as `Nt`, is calculated like this :

`Nt = N0 * e^rt`, where `N0` is the population at time and `r` is the growth rate.

Now, let' assume each person produces a certain amount of gold per unit of time, again this is calculated continuously, What I'm not sure of is how can I get the total amount produced in a given amount of time.

My guess :

my intuitive guess is `N0 * e^rt * GoldPerTimeUnit` but I can't really explain if or why this is correct.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a$ denote what you call "GoldPerUnitTime".

At a specific point of time, the amount of gold produced is what you write:

$$aN_0 e^{rt}$$

So to sum up the amount of gold produced in, say, $C$ time units, we would take an integral:

$$\int_0^C aN_0 e^{rt}$$

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, That does makse sense was indeed what I had in mind in one way or another, Wasn't quite sure it was correct. Much appreciated.